# Is the Windows 7 "Problem Steps Recorder" a part of a larger program they sell?

Tags: windows-7, screen-recorder

Is the Windows 7 "Problem Steps Recorder" a part of a larger program they sell? It does a great job, but I would like it to be a little more full featured. Possibly using it for creating software manuals for example.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Never used this but came up in a search

> Imago Recorder 1.2 is a Screen Capture product from pagefile.de, Imago Recorder can record the activities of the system operations. A simple tool that can record the system activity, which enables report content to be saved for later recall and review by a third person. Numerous settings can be changed. The result is a zippded report with screenshots and a system status that can be easily send via email. SoftSea.com had fully tested, reviewed and uploaded the install files, Imago Recorder does not contain any adware or spyware, the latest version is 1.2, you can download this screen capture software (3.39 MB) from special server of SoftSea.com. The license of this graphic software is Freeware, you can free download and free use this screen capture software.

http://www.softsea.com/review/Imago-Recorder.html

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately, no.  I do think there's a market for a product like this (and maybe somebody will chime in with a 3rd party product that does this).